# In SQL Server, how to fire an event after inserting data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Asset` with columns `Ast_No PK int` (Is Identity="Yes") and `Ast_Number` and `Ast_Date`.

When the client enters data into `Asset`, then `Ast_Number` should be generated automatically by SQL Server and should and look like `AST-B-(Ast_No)`.

How to do this?

Thanks
Basit.

Answer (score 1):

Add a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Asset
  (Ast_No INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Ast_Number AS 'AST-B-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Ast_No AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Asset` without specifying values for `AstNo` or `Ast_Number`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Asset(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `Ast_No` value, and `Ast_Number` will contain values like `AST-B-00001`, `AST-B-00002`,...... 
and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Comment: @user3069097: If you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.